# how to use datagrid view cells values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

```
 for (int  i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {            
     it = db.items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.rakmsanf == Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value ));
     it.quantity =(Convert .ToInt32 ( it.quantity )+Convert.ToInt32 ( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value)).ToString ();
 }
```

trying to use column2 value to update

**Quantity**   and make it  = **Quantity** +column2 value which item name  = other value in other column

[image]

Comment: so whats the code give your error.describe your problem here.

Comment: i attached photo try to  describe my problem

Comment: I can't undestand your language can you post the column in english language.

Comment: use Quantity Column (Column7)  to increase quantity record in database where 
Itemname = column3

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing {} between for loop.

```
for (int  i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
       it = db.items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.rakmsanf == Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value ));
       it.quantity =(Convert .ToInt32 ( it.quantity )+Convert.ToInt32 ( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value)).ToString ();  
 }
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.